# webscrape not finding correct division class, I think

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm looking to try my hand at webscraping. I've written the following python code, but when I go to verify that my code is correctly pulling all the containers, the program returns 0 number of containers.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

# opens walmart's overall webpage, stores into weeklyAd_html variable
url = 'https://www.walmart.com/store/2546/orange-ca/weekly-ads'
uClient = urlopen(url)
weeklyAd_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#performs html parsing
weeklyAdPage_soup = BeautifulSoup(weeklyAd_html, "html.parser")

#throws the pop up of each sale item into the containers variable. atleast, that's what it's supposed to do
containers = weeklyAdPage_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-pop-v3-main goog-modalpopup wishabi-modal-pop"})
```

when I paste this into the command line to test for bugs, I'll ask for `len(containers)` and it returns 0. where am I going wrong? [cmd preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7DPK.png)

Comment: Have you checked the HTML source which your get from the request in your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flyer is from the iframe, which is not present in the page source.

Here's is the flyer url

```
https://weeklyads.walmart.com/flyer_selector/walmartusa?action=show&locale=en-US&store_code=2546&type=2
```

for

```
https://www.walmart.com/store/2546/orange-ca/weekly-ads
```

You can obtain the store_code from the store url and you only need to replace store_code in the flyer url with that value.

Comment: thanks! that's super helpful! I've a lot to learn, so thanks for helping me out!